# Def and PyScript

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, pycharm

I've made a very basic share price prediction script which essentially uses linear regression. Not accurate, but it's proof of concept for a uni project.

I want to add these prices to my website using the new PyScript Library. However, when i run the code on my website, I get this error:

PythonError: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/lib/python3.10/asyncio/futures.py", line 201, in result raise self._exception File "/lib/python3.10/asyncio/tasks.py", line 232, in __step result = coro.send(None) File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pyodide/_base.py", line 506, in eval_code_async await CodeRunner( File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pyodide/_base.py", line 357, in run_async coroutine = eval(self.code, globals, locals) File "", line 6, in File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 311, in wrapper return func(*args, **kwargs) File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py", line 680, in read_csv return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds) File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py", line 575, in _read parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds) File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py", line 933, in **init** self._engine = self._make_engine(f, self.engine) File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py", line 1217, in _make_engine self.handles = get_handle( # type: ignore[call-overload] File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py", line 670, in get_handle ioargs = _get_filepath_or_buffer( File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py", line 339, in _get_filepath_or_buffer with urlopen(req_info) as req: File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py", line 239, in urlopen return urllib.request.urlopen(*args, **kwargs) File "/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 216, in urlopen return opener.open(url, data, timeout) File "/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 519, in open response = self._open(req, data) File "/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 541, in _open return self._call_chain(self.handle_open, 'unknown', File "/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 496, in _call_chain result = func(*args) File "/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 1419, in unknown_open raise URLError('unknown url type: %s' % type) urllib.error.URLError:

This solution worked absolutely fine in pyCharm, so im assunming it's something to do with PyScript?

I'll link the code below.

```
<py-script>
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

urlAAPL = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Dan168/-DanCreates/main/AAPL.csv"
dataAAPL = pd.read_csv(urlAAPL)
XAAPL = dataAAPL.iloc[:, 0].values.reshape(-1, 1)
YAAPL = dataAAPL.iloc[:, 1].values.reshape(-1, 1)

urlAMZN = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Dan168/-DanCreates/main/AMZN.csv"
dataAMZN = pd.read_csv(urlAMZN)
XAMZN = dataAMZN.iloc[:, 0].values.reshape(-1, 1)
YAMZN = dataAMZN.iloc[:, 1].values.reshape(-1, 1)

urlTSLA = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Dan168/-DanCreates/main/TSLA.csv"
dataTSLA = pd.read_csv(urlTSLA)
XTSLA = dataTSLA.iloc[:, 0].values.reshape(-1, 1)
YTSLA = dataTSLA.iloc[:, 1].values.reshape(-1, 1)

urlNIO = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Dan168/-DanCreates/main/NIO.csv"
dataNIO = pd.read_csv(urlNIO)
XNIO = dataNIO.iloc[:, 0].values.reshape(-1, 1)
YNIO = dataNIO.iloc[:, 1].values.reshape(-1, 1)


def Predict(X, Y, Name):
   lr = LinearRegression()
   lr.fit(X, Y)

   Y_pred = lr.predict(X)

   oneDay = 127
   oneWeek = 134
   oneMonth = 156

   print(str(Name))

   print("Price prediction one day day from now: ")
   print(lr.predict(np.array([oneDay]).reshape(-1, 1)))

   print("Price prediction one week day from now: ")
   print(lr.predict(np.array([oneWeek]).reshape(-1, 1)))

   print("Price prediction one month day from now: ")
   print(lr.predict(np.array([oneMonth]).reshape(-1, 1)))


Predict(XAAPL, YAAPL, "AAPL")
Predict(XNIO, YNIO, "NIO")
Predict(XTSLA, YTSLA, "TSLA")
Predict(XAMZN, YAMZN, "AMZN")
</py-script>
```

Ran the code in PyCharm and it worked absolutely fine. Ran fine on my website before when it was just checking one CSV. When I added the method and more stocks to check, this is when I encounted the error - hence making me thing it is something to do with the method??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure that is the full error message? If not, can you post (and properly format) the full error message?

Comment: ("and properly format" is critical -- the newlines are required for readability)

Comment: ...all that said... if pyscript is embedding your script inside of an XML document, you probably should have the text in a CDATA section so it doesn't get munged. I don't see anything in your code that being included directly in an XML document would directly break, but it's tricky to desk-check at a glance; better safe than sorry &c.

Comment: BTW, why not have your function do the download and reshape too?

Comment: It may be a version issue.  Pandas on py-script has historically not supported http inputs.  Check here: https://github.com/amrrs/pyscript-read-csv/blob/main/index.html

Comment: @TimRoberts Cheers mate, it needed the open_url before defining the link. Really appreciate it :)